# Timer job history table has more number of records. Will that cause any issue?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, timer-jobs

We have a SharePoint 2013 env, it has TimerJobHistory table contains:   1154486   rows.

Will this be any issue?

If this is an issue, how can we purge the data?

Purging data will cause and issue and do we need to take a backup of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can reduce the amount of data being deleted by the timer job during each run, so I need to modify the daystokeephistory value of the timer job.

The following PowerShell script for your reference:

```
$history = Get-SPTimerJob | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "job-delete-job-history"}

$history.daystokeephistory = 25

$history.update()

$history.runnow()
```

More information:

http://convergingpoint.blogspot.com/2012/05/sharepoint-configuration-database-too.html

Comment: With that many rows, this is inadvisable and will likely fail. Instead, opening up a PSS case who can provide a supported solution for manually trimming the table directly is the most appropriate course of action.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I had to purge the data and set it for 3 days as I faced performance-related issues.